# pyspark dataframe filter using variable list values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a requirment to filter the pyspark dataframe where user will pass directly the filter column part as a string parameter. For example:

```
Sample Input data: df_input

|dim1|dim2|  byvar|value1|value2|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    10|
| 201| 202|MTD0002|     2|    12|
| 301| 302|MTD0003|     3|    13|
| 401| 402|MTD0004|     5|    19|
```

Ex 1: filter_str = "dim2 = '201'"

```
I will filter the data as: df_input = df_input.filter(filter_str)

Output: (**I'm able to get the output**)

|dim1|dim2|  byvar|value1|value2|
| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    10|
```

But, for multiple filter condition I'm getting error and not able to filter.
**Scenario where I'm not able to filter the input dataframe:**

**valid Scr 1:**

```
filter_str = "dim1 = '101' and dim2 in '['302', '402']'"
df_inp = df_inp.filter(filter_str)
Getting Error
```

**valid Scr 2:**

```
value_list = ['302', '402']
filter_str = "dim1 = '101' or dim2 in '(value_list)'"
df_inp = df_inp.filter(filter_str)
Getting Error
```

Could you please help in acheiving the scr 1 and 2 and how to modify the filter section if i get the filter_str string as mentioned I example.

Comment: Is there any reason for using for writing condition in string instead of writing actual condition?

Comment: its part of requirement i got where user pass the filter condition as a parameter ( in string type) along with filter column and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`&`** (or) **`|`** operators in your **filter** query and enclose each statement with brackets `()`.

```
df.filter((col("dim1") == '101') | (col("dim2").isin(['302','402']))).show()
#+----+----+-------+------+------+
#|dim1|dim2|  byvar|value1|value2|
#+----+----+-------+------+------+
#| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    10|
#| 301| 302|MTD0003|     3|    13|
#| 401| 402|MTD0004|     5|    19|
#+----+----+-------+------+------+

df.filter((col("dim1") == '101') & (col("dim2").isin(['302','402']))).show()
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
#|dim1|dim2|byvar|value1|value2|
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
```

**`Using expr:`**

Here we need to convert **list** to **`tuple`** to perform `in` on `value_list`

```
#using filter_str
value_list = ['302', '402']
filter_str = "dim1 = '101' or dim2 in {0}".format(tuple(value_list))
filter_str
#"dim1 = '101' or dim2 in ('302', '402')"
df.filter(expr(filter_str)).show()
#+----+----+-------+------+------+
#|dim1|dim2|  byvar|value1|value2|
#+----+----+-------+------+------+
#| 101| 201|MTD0001|     1|    10|
#| 301| 302|MTD0003|     3|    13|
#| 401| 402|MTD0004|     5|    19|
#+----+----+-------+------+------+

filter_str = "dim1 = '101' and dim2 in {0}".format(tuple(value_list))
df.filter(expr(filter_str)).show()
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
#|dim1|dim2|byvar|value1|value2|
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
#+----+----+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response it helps. Why we are not getting output for the and condition??

Comment: @SureshGudimetla, we don't have rows matching `dim1=101` and `dim2 =302 or dim2=402`!

Comment: sorry i got it, and it worked fine...able to complete the coding part. Thank you